# Scrapy only get the data of last page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using python 3.6 and scrapy 2.4.1, and I wrote a spider to scrape about 5 pages, then use xlsxwriter to save to excel, however this scarpy only get last page data, can't figure out why, here is my spider code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ebay.items import EbayItem


class EbaySpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ebay_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.ebay.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/auplazaplace/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        item_price_extract = []
        item_title = []
        item_title_list = response.xpath('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a')
        item_href = response.xpath('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a/@href').getall()
        for title in item_title_list:
            item_title_text = title.xpath('string(.)').get()
            item_title.append(item_title_text)
        item_price = response.xpath('//li[@class="lvprice prc"]//span[@class="bold"]')
        for i in range(len(item_price)):
            item_price_text = item_price[i].xpath('string(.)').get()
            item_price_extract.append(item_price_text.strip())
        item_info = EbayItem(title=item_title, price=item_price_extract, item_href=item_href)
        yield item_info
        next_url_href = response.xpath('//a[@class="gspr next"]/@href').get()
        if not next_url_href:
            return
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url_href, callback=self.parse)
```

and pipeline code

```
import xlsxwriter


class EbayPipeline:
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        pass

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        col_num = 0
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\Users\Clevo\Desktop\store_spider.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        item_source = dict(item)
        # print(item_source)
        for key, values in item_source.items():
            worksheet.write(0, col_num, key)
            worksheet.write_column(1, col_num, values)
            col_num += 1
        workbook.close()
        return item
```

someone know the reason why? it seems everything is ok, but I can only get last page data

by the way, is there anyway to transfer data to another function? I want to scrapy page detail and transfer the data to process_item function and yield them together

Comment: You don't have to add `www` in allowed domain. Change `['www.ebay.com.au']` to `['ebay.com.au']` (refer: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains)

Comment: Wait, I will restructure your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better scraped every pages first and get data on its product page.

```
class EbaySpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ebay_spider"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = 'https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/auplazaplace/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs='
        for i in range(1,6):
            page = base_url + str(i)#i will be the page number and add to base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url=page , callback=self.parse)

    # scraped all product links first and yield to parse_contents
    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_contents)

    #scraped desired data on product page
    def parse_contents(self, response):
        product_url = response.url
        title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract()[0]
        price = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').extract()[0]
        item = EbayItem()
        item['product_title'] = title
        item['product_price'] = price
        yield item ### to items.py
```

items.py, make sure that the item keys are equal to scrapy.Field()

```
class EbayITem(scrapy.Item):
    product_title = scrapy.Field()
    product_price = scrapy.Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
import xlsxwriter


class EbayPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        title = item['product_title']
        price = item['product_price']
        #process your worksheet here
```

Answer (score 0):

Working version of your code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from ebay.items import EbayItem


class EbaySpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ebay_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['ebay.com.au']
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/auplazaplace/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        item_price_extract = []
        item_title = []
        item_title_list = response.xpath('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a')
        item_href = response.xpath('//h3[@class="lvtitle"]/a/@href').getall()
        for title in item_title_list:
            item_title_text = title.xpath('string(.)').get()
            item_title.append(item_title_text)
        item_price = response.xpath('//li[@class="lvprice prc"]//span[@class="bold"]')
        for i in range(len(item_price)):
            item_price_text = item_price[i].xpath('string(.)').get()
            item_price_extract.append(item_price_text.strip())
        item_info = EbayItem(title=item_title, price=item_price_extract, item_href=item_href)
        yield item_info
        next_url_href = response.xpath('//a[@class="gspr next"]/@href').get()
        if next_url_href is not None:
            next_url_href = response.urljoin(next_url_href)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url_href, callback=self.parse)
```

You will have to set `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in settings.py (which is not a good practice) or else it your spider won't scrape data and will give message:
`[scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.ebay.com.au/sch/auplazaplace/m.html?_nkw=&_armrs=1>`